# Can not make a 'non-const for range' inside a const member function

Tags: c++, for-loop, constants

IN this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  class Bar {
  public:
    int bar;
  };
  class Foo {
  public:
      std::vector<Bar> myBars;
      Bar &getOneBar() const {
        for( Bar &bar : myBars ) {
            return bar;
        }
      }
  };
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error: binding ‘const main(int, char**)::Bar’ to reference of type ‘main(int, char**)::Bar&’ discards qualifiers
```

Which I accept, but don't understand, as I am not modifying the content of the class in that function. I understand that I could modify the object after the call to getOneBar(), but not inside.

I have resolved it with a const_cast, but I kind of not like that.

```
 Bar &getOneBar() const {
        for( Bar &bar : myBars ) {
            return const_cast<Bar &>(bar);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `for( Bar const &bar : myBars )` be better than casting? (And returning a non-const reference from a `const` function seems odd to me.)

Comment: It makes no difference, I get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that I could modify the object after the call to getOneBar(), but not inside.

It's just not allowed. More precisely, data members are considered as `const` inside the `const` member function. Then `myBars` becomes `const std::vector<Bar>`, and element returned from it becomes `const` too; it doesn't match the return type `Bar &`, you can't bind a reference to non-const to a `const`.

As you said, `const_cast` is a bad idea. The more clear way should be to declare both `const` and non-`const` member function overload, e.g.

```
const Bar& getOneBar() const {
    for (const Bar &bar : myBars) {
        return bar;
    }
}

Bar& getOneBar() {
    for (Bar &bar : myBars) {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with @songyuanyao, but what I don't understand is why I must  lose the const optimization of the first overload when I use the second one if the only thing I want is to find a bar, and that operation doesn't change my object.

Comment: @Santilín Returning a reference which might be modified just makes `const` member function contradictory and confusing, it doesn't make sense.